# Is it possible to load ListPreference items from an adapter?

Tags: android, arrays, preferences, adapter

I'm setting out to create a settings activity for my app. I've defined a `PreferenceActivity` with a nice layout including a `ListPreference` object for the user to select a bluetooth device. **I'm having trouble dynamically populating the list**.

**I would like to populate `ListPreference` with values from an array adapter** (which I'll create and populate with relevant bluetooth device names).

If this were a spinner View, I could just call `setAdapter()`. However with the `ListPreference` object I can't figure out how to attach an adapter (`findviewByID` won't cast from View To `ListPreference`, so I can't even get a handle to the object).

I would like to attach an adapter and then populate the adapter with values, which in turn would populate the `ListPreference` with values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ListPreference` doesn't work with adapters, it works with strings. See [`setEntries()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#setEntries(java.lang.CharSequence[])) and [`setEntryValues()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#setEntryValues(java.lang.CharSequence[]))

To get at your `ListPreference`, call [`findPreference()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence)) on your `PreferenceActivity`. Cast the `Preference` you get back to `ListPreference`.

Comment: This is not true, you can set an adapter to the builder in the `onPrepareDialogBuilder` callback.

Answer (score 10):

For the special case of a list of bluetooth devices, you can use the following class:

```
package de.duenndns;

import android.bluetooth.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

import java.util.Set;

public class BluetoothDevicePreference extends ListPreference {

    public BluetoothDevicePreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        BluetoothAdapter bta = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bta.getBondedDevices();
        CharSequence[] entries = new CharSequence[pairedDevices.size()];
        CharSequence[] entryValues = new CharSequence[pairedDevices.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (BluetoothDevice dev : pairedDevices) {
            entries[i] = dev.getName();
            if (entries[i] == null) entries[i] = "unknown";
            entryValues[i] = dev.getAddress();
            i++;
        }
        setEntries(entries);
        setEntryValues(entryValues);
    }

    public BluetoothDevicePreference(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

}
```

It can be involved directly from your prefs XML to store the MAC as a prefs string:

```
<de.duenndns.BluetoothDevicePreference
    android:key="bluetooth_mac"
    android:title="Bluetooth Device"
    android:dialogTitle="Choose Bluetooth Device" />
```

Comment: First of all: thank you all for that piece of code. It is working well. but in I´ve got an rendering problem in the preview in AS.  `Rendering Problems  java.lang.NullPointerException   at de.jphjung.speedcamssiegerland.BluetoothDevicePreference.<init>(BluetoothDevicePreference.java:20)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:385) [...and some more...too much for that character limit here]`

Answer (score 5):

Just an Update to this in case someone else comes along, ge0rg answer works but changed it a little to take in consideration of multiple preferences and not just the bluetooth one and also if they dont have any paired devices set up so you dont get an error with a null array.

```
ListPreference BTList = (ListPreference) findPreference("your preference key");
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    CharSequence[] entries = new CharSequence[1];
    CharSequence[] entryValues = new CharSequence[1];
    entries[0] = "No Devices";
    entryValues[0] = "";
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0){
        entries = new CharSequence[pairedDevices.size()];
        entryValues = new CharSequence[pairedDevices.size()];
        int i=0;
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices){
            entries[i] = device.getName();
            entryValues[i] = device.getAddress();
            i++;
        }
    }
    BTList.setEntries(entries);
    BTList.setEntryValues(entryValues);
```

`Hope this helps someone...oh and this is put under the onCreate method for the preference activity

Answer (score 4):

Another way would be to override [onPrepareDialogBuilder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/ListPreference.html#onPrepareDialogBuilder%28android.app.AlertDialog.Builder%29) of ListPreference and to initialize [setSingleChoiceItems](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setSingleChoiceItems%28android.widget.ListAdapter,%20int,%20android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener%29) of AlertDialog.Builder directly with your adapter:

```
public class AdapterListPreference extends ListPreference
{
    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder( AlertDialog.Builder builder )
    {
        // don't call super.onPrepareDialogBuilder() because it'll check
        // for Entries and set up a setSingleChoiceItems() for them that
        // will never be used

        final ListAdapter adapter = …;

        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(
            adapter,
            0,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which )
                {
                    // adapter.getItemId( which )

                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            } );

        builder.setPositiveButton( null, null );
    }
}
```

If you look at the Android sources, you'll find that onPrepareDialogBuilder() does call:

```
public AlertDialog.Builder setSingleChoiceItems (CharSequence[] items, int checkedItem, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
```

with those entry arrays. To make ListPreference use some adapter (e.g. ArrayAdaper, CursorAdapter), you just need to call:

```
public AlertDialog.Builder setSingleChoiceItems (ListAdapter adapter, int checkedItem, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)
```

instead.

This way ListPreference will operate on the adapter directly and you don't need to copy the data from the adapter to put them into the entries arrays.

Find a working sample [here](https://github.com/markusfisch/ShaderEditor/blob/master/src/de/markusfisch/android/shadereditor/ShaderListPreference.java).