# Fill ListPreference contents from Activity

Tags: java, android, listpreference

I am trying to fill up my ListPreference from within my Activity rather than have the array stored in xml. However I am finding this problematic. I may be setting up my preferences wrong. I have access to my ListPreference however filling the content dynamically I can't seem to get. I have looked at this post. [Is it possible to load ListPreference items from an adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936919/is-it-possible-to-load-listpreference-items-from-an-adapter) but I can't seem to figure it out from this.

I am trying to occupy the ListPreference with Strings from a List of objects.

This is what I have so far:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(LUAS_TIMES_PREF, 0);

    ListPreference lp = (ListPreference)findPreference("station_pref");

}
```

Not much but how can I fill this list preference with my own list?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you not want to store the list of preferences in XML?

Comment: I have a raw resource of JSON Objects that I read in and fill a list. I then want to use that list to occupy the ListPreference so if the user has a preference to start the app displaying a default object it will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
lp.setEntries(new String [] {"A Man", "A Plan"}); // set displayed text
lp.setEntryValues(new String [] {"a_man", "a_plan"}); // set associated values
```

Extrapolate as required :)

Comment: Thanks, seems the problem is deeper rooted. What am I not doing if this is printed in the LogCat: 06-21 13:13:27.515: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(605): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ListPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array.

Comment: Hi @Hugo what was the reason and solution to the IllegalStateException that you mentioned in comment?